# can't serialize class in MongoDB Java and String are encoded

Tags: java, json, mongodb

My simple application is suppose to just populate MongoDB with a mapping between `_id` to `user`. My key (`_id`) is in JSON format and its value is just a long.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "a": "1B2ac",
        "b": "Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:16.0 Ff/6.0"
    },
    "user": 1999129
}
```

I have a couple of issues:

Issue 1: I get `can's serialize class...` when I try to insert:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class test.mongo.foo.DummyObject
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:234)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:121)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:102)
    at     com.test.mongo.foo.DaoImpl.insertRecords(DaoImpl.java:130)
```

Here is my class for the `DummyObject` (which implements `Serializable`):

```
 package test.mongo.foo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class DummyObject implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2715467675581503964L;

    //default constructor
    public DummyObject(){

    }

    private String a;
    private String b;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

Here is my `DaoImp` Class

```
package test.mongo.foo;
public class DaoImpl extends MongoDAOImpl{

    public int insertRecords(List<DBObject> records) {
        DBCollection coll = getDBCollection();

        Exception e = null;
        try {
            WriteResult res =  coll.insert(records);
            if (res.getError() != null) {
                throw new MongoRuntimeException(res.getError());
            }
            return res.getN();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            e = err;
            throw new MongoRuntimeException(err);
        }
    }

    public static DBObject convertToDBObject(DummyObject obj, long value) {
        DBObject bdbo = new BasicDBObject();
        bdbo.put("_id",obj);
        bdbo.put("user",value);
        return bdbo;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
          DummyObject d = new DummyObject();
           d.setA("1B2ac");
           d.setB("Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:16.0 Ff/6.0");
           long val = 1999129;
           List<DBObject> l = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
           l.add(DaoImpl.convertToDBObject(d,val));
           DaoImpl impl = new DaoImpl();
    }
}
```

**ISSUE 2:** To avoid the above issue, I tried to insert the record with String to String mapping. Though my input String (for `_id`) is not escaped, `DBObject` escapes it internally and eventually writes to the MongoDB as the following:

```
{
    "_id": {
        \"a\": \"1B2ac\",
        \"b\": \"WindowsNT5.2;WOW64;rv: 16.0Ff/6.0\"
    },
    "user": NumberLong(1999129)
}
```

INSTEAD OF

```
{
    "_id": {
        "a": "1B2ac",
        "b": "Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:16.0 Ff/6.0"
    },
    "user": 1999129
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve both these issues? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I found answer to my own question after playing around a little with it. Inserting as a JsonObject. I converted my DummyObject to JsonObject/Object (hint: Json.parse(jstr))

Thanks
Masti